# JSchException while using Jgit api

Tags: ant, jsch

I'm trying to clone my git repository using Jgit and I get this exception:

```
 `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/JSchException
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.<clinit>(Transport.java:112)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:178)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:125)
 `
```

I downloaded and copied Jsch in /lib and restarted my application (since Jgit has dependencies on this jar), I still get the same error. I'm running a java application build using ant from command line. Any other details please let me know.

Comment: Which lib folder is it ? It must be Ant's one or the one in ~/.ant

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I load optional task sshexec into Ant in a no-configuration manner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752124/how-do-i-load-optional-task-sshexec-into-ant-in-a-no-configuration-manner)